# How do I get an element inside a div to follow the cursor without going outside the parent?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a div follow the cursor in a parent div, and I got it semi working, but it keeps going outside of the parent div slightly on the right side and on the bottom side of the parent div. I tried to make an if statement for if it goes above an x/y position then it has to stop, but that didn't work.

```js
var shipp = document.getElementById("spaceship");

document.getElementById("ship-container").addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  shipp.style.left = x + "px";
  shipp.style.top = y + "px";
  document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "X:" + x + " Y:" + y;
});
```

```html
<p style="color: white;" id="disp"></p>
<div class="ship" id="ship-container">
  <div class="spaceship" id="spaceship"><img class="spaceship-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/27443m1/spaceship.png" alt="spaceship"></div>

</div>

<p style="color: white;" id="disp"></p>
```

Here is the codepen to show how it keeps going outside of the parent div: https://codepen.io/metmouse/pen/rNxRymP

Comment: Can you insert your example code into an interactive snippet so that we can run it in the browser? That way you'll be certain you've provided a good example, and we'll be able to see exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: ok ill link the codepen

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "position: relative" on element which 'left' and 'top' you are actually modifying:

```js
var shipp = document.getElementById("spaceship");

document.getElementById("ship-container").addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  shipp.style.left = x + "px";
  shipp.style.top = y + "px";
  document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "X:" + x + " Y:" + y;
});
```

```html
<p style = "color: black;" id = "disp"></p>
<div  class = "ship" id = "ship-container">
  <div style="position:relative" class = "spaceship" id = "spaceship"><img class = "spaceship-img" src = "https://i.ibb.co/27443m1/spaceship.png" alt = "spaceship"></div>
    
</div>
```

Not sure if this is the desired effect, though.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem too keep the div from going outside of the parent